# Searching C# code for missing calls

Tags: c#, search

In one of our C# projects, each method should have auditing around it. We have an auditing class that we use for performing audits, but what I'm wondering, if is anyone knows a way that I can search all public methods of a specific project and alert on any method that does not have at least one call to the auditing class.

Any things on how I can do this?

Comment: I can't help but think that doing this in code is brittle; there are technologies for adding cross-cutting concerns into code - of example PostSharp/SharpCrafters for concrete class-level, or any number of automatic interface/subclass decorators if you can use a decorator approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [NDepend.com](http://NDepend.com). With this cool tool such code queries are possible!!

The query should be something like

```
SELECT METHODS WHERE IsPublic AND NOT IsDirectlyUsing "YourNamespace.AuditingMethod()"
```

Comment: Indeed, the `IsUsing` CQL filter looks promising

Comment: "IsDirectlyUsing" is better than "IsUsing", the latter will not (in this case) flag methods that don't call the auditing method, so long as they call other methods that do call the auditing method. In other words, if A calls B, and B calls Audit, IsDirectlyUsing will in this case flag A as missing the call, but IsUsing will not.